# What formula is used in get_influence() function in statsmodel.api in python?

Tags: python, model, regression, statsmodels, outliers

I am using get_influence function in python code to calculated Cook's disances but i would like to describe the formula it is using, ideally is there any official documentation about this? I cant find anything. Thanks

```
model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

influence = model.get_influence() # create instance of influence
cooks_distances = influence.cooks_distance
```

Answer (score 1):

part of docstring and code for cook's distance in OLS

```
        References
        ----------
        .. [*] Eubank, R. L. (1999). Nonparametric regression and spline
            smoothing. CRC press.
        .. [*] Cook's distance. (n.d.). In Wikipedia. July 2019, from
            https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance
        """
        hii = self.hat_matrix_diag
        # Eubank p.93, 94
        cooks_d2 = self.resid_studentized ** 2 / self.k_vars
        cooks_d2 *= hii / (1 - hii)
```

(In general outlier and influence measures for OLS were written mostly based on SAS examples and documentation. e.g. https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/statug/statug_reg_details25.htm and related pages)